# Lectura de Json en Pyton

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I need to read a JSON file, I need to take the attributes of each of the customers and enter them into a list but, if I print with `print (data.get ('products') [0])` it prints the products of both customer 80849599 and customer 1022734737

How can I print only customer 1 information?

```
[{
        "cliente": "80849599",
        "productos": [{
                "nombre": "Chocolatinas Cohete",
                "cantidad": 3,
                "precio unitario": 300
            },
            {
                "nombre": "Mora",
                "cantidad": 1,
                "precio unitario": 1000
            },
            {
                "nombre": "Pan de Maiz",
                "cantidad": 5,
                "precio unitario": 300
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cliente": "1022734737",
        "productos": [{
                "nombre": "Televisor",
                "cantidad": 2,
                "precio unitario": 1500000
            },
            {
                "nombre": "Teatro en Casa",
                "cantidad": 1,
                "precio unitario": 450000
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  There is no structure `data` in your post.  The data you provide has no key `"products"`.  You need to locate the desired customer by client ID number and print the product information form that dict only.  The code to do this is covered in many existing resources on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on line.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way just use:

```
print(myjson[0]['productos'])
```

Otherwise Try to filter with cliente number like this:

```
myjson = [{
        "cliente": "80849599",
        "productos": [{
                "nombre": "Chocolatinas Cohete",
                "cantidad": 3,
                "precio unitario": 300
            },
            {
                "nombre": "Mora",
                "cantidad": 1,
                "precio unitario": 1000
            },
            {
                "nombre": "Pan de Maiz",
                "cantidad": 5,
                "precio unitario": 300
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cliente": "1022734737",
        "productos": [{
                "nombre": "Televisor",
                "cantidad": 2,
                "precio unitario": 1500000
            },
            {
                "nombre": "Teatro en Casa",
                "cantidad": 1,
                "precio unitario": 450000
            }
        ]
    }
]

for x in myjson:
  if x['cliente'] == "80849599":
    print(x['productos'])
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say that we loaded the json file above as "f"

and I'll also assume "customer 1" is the first ""cliente"

```py
import json

print(f[0]["cliente"]) #prints 80849599
print(f[0]["productos"][0]["nombre"]) #prints "Chocolatinas Cohete"
```

remember that there is a list

Answer (score 0):

To use JSON in Python, you will need the library **json**.

Example:

```
import json

jsonData = '[{"cliente":"80849599","productos":[{"nombre":"Chocolatinas Cohete","cantidad":3,"precio unitario":300},{"nombre":"Mora","cantidad":1,"precio unitario":1000},{"nombre":"Pan de Maiz","cantidad":5,"precio unitario":300}]},{"cliente":"1022734737","productos":[{"nombre":"Televisor","cantidad":2,"precio unitario":1500000},{"nombre":"Teatro en Casa","cantidad":1,"precio unitario":450000}]}]'

# JSON to Python:
pythonData = json.loads(jsonData)

# Getting data
print(pythonData[0]["productos"][0]['nombre'])
```

This script return: Chocolatinas Cohete.

[More details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)